# how to add token in httpurlconnection class

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

i am using this code for API access.But i have no idea how to add token as header in httpurlconnection class.my tag for token is "token".I want to add "token" tag with token value in header field but i have no idea.i have googled but i am confused

```
  public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String murl, Utils.method m, Map<String, String> parmas, String Token, String filepath, String filefield, String filemimetype){
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****" + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "*****";
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String urlTo = SERVER_PATH + murl;

    String result = "";

    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlTo);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
  //            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android Multipart HTTP Client 1.0");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        if (Token != null){
            connection.setRequestProperty("token", "Basic " + new String(Base64.encode(Token.getBytes(), 0)));
        }

        outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        if (filepath != null) {
            String[] q = filepath.split("/");
            int idx = q.length - 1;
            File file = new File(filepath);
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + filefield + "\"; filename=\"" + q[idx] + "\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: " + filemimetype + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" + lineEnd);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        }
        //            outputStream.writeBytes(getQuery(parmas));
        Iterator<String> keys = parmas.keySet().iterator();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = keys.next();
            String value = parmas.get(key);
            System.out.println("Key :"+key+" and Value :"+value);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + key + "\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(value);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        }
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
        System.out.println("Response Code :"+connection.getResponseCode());
        if (200 != connection.getResponseCode()) {

        }

        inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

        result = this.convertStreamToString(inputStream);
        jobj = new JSONObject(result);
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        connection.disconnect();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jobj;
}
```

Comment: you are doing it correct, but the header name is **"Authorization"** not `token` replace it and try

Comment: still it is not working